# How can I redirect STDERR output to a variable or function to be later appended to a log file?

Tags: bash, function, shell, redirect, stderr

This is how I'm trying to redirect *only the STDERR output* from `apt` to a log file, while the `apt` progress report is visible on the terminal using function `log_trace()` twice:

```bash
apt update 2> >(log_trace "(APT)") | while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line != "All packages are up to date." ]]; then
        bool_update_required=1
    fi
    log_trace "(APT)" <<<"$line"
done
```

The problem is since each output line is processed in the loop twice, I get custom line prefix `» (APT)` from `log_trace()` (actually from another function `__logger_core`) printed twice as well:

```
  » (APT)   » (APT)   
  » (APT)   » (APT) WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.  
  » (APT)   » (APT)   
  » (APT) Reading package lists... 
  » (APT)   » (APT) E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 1490 (packagekitd)  
  » (APT)   » (APT) E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/  
  » (APT)   » (APT) E: Problem renaming the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin.J7Fixb to /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - rename (2: No such file or directory)  
  » (APT)   » (APT) W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems  
  » (APT)   » (APT) E: The package cache file is corrupted
```

And this is the function itself:

```bash
log_trace() {
    local line
    # Output automatically written to $_LOG_FILE
    # Arguments: 1
    # ARG -1: printf variable for formatting the log
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        __logger_core "trace" "$(printf "%s %s" "${1:-UNKNOWN}" "$line")"
    done
}
```

How can I achieve something like this:

```
  » (APT) This is just a progress report, no error or warning
  » (APT) You don't see STDERR output because it safely resides in the log file already
  » (APT) All packages are up to date.
```

Thank you!

Comment: How to you go from 9 lines of (wrong) output to 3 lines of (desired) output? please update the question to insure both sets of output (wrong, desired) correspond to the same set of inputs

Comment: Both output come from `apt`, with the (wrong==stderr) output intended to go to the log file without showing in the terminal, except the `apt` progress (desired) report.

Comment: Your trial-and-error result, insofar as it solves your problem, should be added with the "add an answer" button, not edited into the question. Answers do not belong in questions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Done as suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error, this works as follows:

```
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == "All packages are up to date." ]]; then
        bool_update_required=0
    fi
    log_trace "(APT)" <<<"$line"
done < <(apt update 2>&1)       # format all `apt` output, incl. errors/warnings
```

In other words, `apt` output, whatever it is, doesn't escape my formatting function `log_trace()`.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow the entirety of what was wrong with the original code, but one of the things this fixes is the issue described in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) causing changes to `bool_update_required` to be discarded when the loop exited.